# Unity initial staging screen before AR camera loads

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

When my Unity app first load I get this staging screen before the AR camera screen.  How do I remove this staging screen?

[Initial Staging Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ1qD.png)

Want to directly display the AR camera without the staging screen.  I’m using AR Foundation and this is on iOS.

[AR Camera screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKCLP.jpg)